# Google Maps API for android used offline account api hits?

Tags: android, google-maps, offline

I am actually developing an iOS/Android application containing a map showing some places. I want to introduce a concept of offline map, in other words I want that the user can, when he is online, download the offline map.

My question is, when the user opens the map in offline mode is a hit counted in google api?
This is in relation to the cost after you get over the 25k hits per day.

Answer (score 1):

"Offline" only means that the map will get cached -- which is otherwise forbidden by Google Maps API terms.

So **yes**, loading a map will count.

But **no**, loading a cached map will not count AFAIK.